# move previous git commits in a subdirectory to a new branch

Tags: git

I need to separate a feature B out of feature A's branch. All B commits are in the same subdirectory, but many of the commits include A & B.

Moving a subdirectory into a new REPO is well documented using git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter, so that's my current line of thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take a look at [`git subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).

This will allow you to do what you're looking to do.

Try out:
`git subtree split -P <subdirectory of feature B> -b <new feat B branch name>`

This new branch name shouldn't exist before the above command.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't want `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter`, since you're still staying in the same repo.

I would just use `git rebase -i` with an `exec` script that resets all changes not made in directory B (or do it by hand if there's little enough).

Note that this will still leave A dirty unless you also rebase that (on top of B if it requires that, or on top of the branch point otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, this should do the trick:

```
# --- Switch to a new branch 
$ git checkout -b feature-b

# --- Get the changes in a specific dir from the feature-a branch
$ git checkout feature-a -- dir/featureB
$ git commit -m"FeatureB from feature-a"

# --- Go back to feature-a and forget about dir/featureB
# --- Note that you need to find oldref
$ git checkout feature-a
$ git reset oldref -- ./dir/featureB
```

The thing with this method is that you don't actually *move the commits* but only the results. If you really care about the history then go for `rebase` or `cheery-pick` based solutions.